# Nested array not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to get access to individual values in an array within an array, I have the overall array, which has arrays in it, and then within that, I want to be able to access those values.

I would also likely assign each of those values to variables.

Essentially I am trying to iterate through what would become a grid of values (an array within an array) using JS.

1) I've tried accessing the value by pushing the row values into the array as a JSON string and then mapping it as array.map => row.map and then mapping it into individual elements

2) I've tried 'destructuring' the object but that did not seem to go anywhere either.

```
async function dataFormat(worksheet, rowNumber) {
  csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile("./uploads/uploadedFile.csv");
  await csvWorkbook.then(async function(result) {
    let restarts = 0;
    let nullCounts = true;
    let thermostatRows = []; 

// you have to define THEN destructure the array
    // const [serial,date,startDate,endDate,thing3,thing4,thing5] = firstTemps

    worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
      if (rowNumber > 6) {
        Rows.push(`${JSON.stringify(row.values)}`);

      }
    });
    console.log(thermostatRows[0])
  })
  };
```

Here is my function that returns the first row. If I put Rows[0][0] I get a letter.

here is the return of Rows[1]

`[null,"2018-12 03T05:00:00.000Z","16:35:00","heat","heatOff", "hold","Home",70.1,70.1,69.8,43,33.8,0,0,15,15,null,69.8,43,1]`

Which makes sense as it is the first row.

but logging Rows[0][0] gives me the first letter of null (first value in the array)

Lastly ,

```
[ '[null,"2018-12-02T05:00:00.000Z","23:25:00","heat","heatOff","auto","Home",72,72,72,47,41.3,0,0,0,0,null,72,47,0]',

  '[null,"2018-12-03T05:00:00.000Z","16:35:00","heat","heatOff","hold","Home",70.1,70.1,69.8,43,33.8,0,0,15,15,null,69.8,43,1]',

'[null,"2018-12 03T05:00:00.000Z","16:40:00",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,33.8,0]'
```

Is the approximate log if I log Rows without anything else - to give you an idea of the whole situation.

edit: my function now looks like this, why would it return undefined?

````
    if (rowNumber > 6) {
      thermostatRows.push((row.values));
    }
  });
  thermostatRows.map(thermostatRow => {
    // let [date,time,SystemSetting,systemMode,calendarEvent,ProgramMode,coolSetTemp,HeatSetTemp,currentTemp,currentHumidity,outdoorTemp,windSpeed,coolStage1,HeatStage1,Fan,DMOffset,thermostatTemperature,thermostatHumidity,thermostatMotion] = thermostatSettings
    console.log(date,time,SystemSetting)
    })
  })
};```

FINAL UPDATE 

It works I figured out the undefined deal myself- try this. (this is with the excel.js library)

  async function dataFormat(worksheet, rowNumber) {
    csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile("./uploads/uploadedFile.csv");
    await csvWorkbook.then(async function(result) {
      let restarts = 0;
      let nullCounts = true;
      let thermostatRows = [];
      let thermostatSettings = []; // you have to define THEN destructure the array
      // const [serial,date,startDate,endDate,thing3,thing4,thing5] = firstTemps

      worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, function(row, rowNumber) {
        if (rowNumber > 6) {
          thermostatRows.push((row.values));
        }
      });
      thermostatRows.map(thermostatRow => { [,date,time,SystemSetting,systemMode,calendarEvent,ProgramMode,coolSetTemp,HeatSetTemp,currentTemp,currentHumidity,outdoorTemp,windSpeed,coolStage1,HeatStage1,Fan,DMOffset,thermostatTemperature,thermostatHumidity,thermostatMotion] = thermostatRow
        console.log(date,time,SystemSetting)
        })
      })
    };
````

Comment: What does eachRow do?

Comment: // Iterate over all rows that have values in a worksheet .. but I need to do that to push those values into an array I can map etc. (I'm working with CSVS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to be aware that Javascript arrays are zero-indexed. This means that to get the FIRST item, you use index 0. When you're calling Rows[1] you're actually getting the second item.

Second, you aren't creating a 2d array, you're creating a one dimensional array of strings.

`` Rows.push(`${JSON.stringify(row.values)}`); ``

This takes `row.values` and turns it into a string, interpolates it into another string, then pushes the final result into the array.

If you want an array inside the first array, which I assume row.values contains, do `Rows.push(row.values);`

Comment: Oh my god , rookie mistake in my description !! [1] was just a test value i was trying to return to figure out what was happening.